# Не удаётся выполнить системную команды в python на windows 7. Разархивирование архива в python

Tags: python, gzip, 7z, winrar

Пытаюсь разархивировать linux-овский архив с помощью программы 7z. Я предварительно добавил путь к 7z в переменной PATH. В консоли - всё получается, однако в коде python res == 1. Также в pycharm консоли вылазиют кракозябры. Как это понимать? Почему в консоли всё нормально, а os.system('команда из консоли') выполняется с ошибкой? Если есть другие способы извлечь архив в python, кроме как через консольную команду - подскажите, буду признателен.

```
path = 'myarc.gz'
res = os.system('7z e "{}"'.format(path))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кстати, текст вашей ошибки выглядит так: '"7z" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.'

Comment: А это вообще возможно? Разве os.system запускает не те команды, которые доступны в моей консоли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автоматическое декодирование:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

path = 'myarc.gz'
ret = run(['7z', 'e' f'{path}'], shell=True,
          check=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
          universal_newlines=True)  # Можно указать кодировку: encoding='cp1251'
print(ret.stdout)
```

Ручное декодирование:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

path = 'myarc.gz'
ret = run(['7z', 'e' f'{path}'], shell=True, check=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print(ret.stdout.decode('utf8'))  # Возможно utf8 следует заменить на cp1251
print(ret.stderr.decode('utf8'))  # Возможно utf8 следует заменить на cp1251
```

После изменения переменных окружения через:

> Панель управления\Все элементы панели управления\Система\Дополнительные параметры системы\Переменные среды\ - Список обновлён

Необходимо перезапустить PyCharm.